# debug an application running with valgrind

Tags: valgrind, gdbserver

I am working on valgrind and want to debug a program while valgrind runs over it.
But i don't want to use the in built `vgdb`, instead i want to use a custom gdb server. 
Is there a way to plugin this custom gdbserver in the existing valgrind code.

thanks

Comment: The idea is that the embedded V gdbserver provides what is needed
for usual debugging.
What kind of specific needs do you have ?

Comment: actually i am not able to debug the program with that gdb. When ever i try to backtrace it shows just the address and cannot resolve the start of the function. 
so i was trying to use the gdb that i had which is customized for the hardware i am using.

Answer (score 0):

Only by patching valgrind.  The valgrind gdbserver implementation is compiled in.

Comment: ya i know but i thought if i could get any help as in where valgrind does this and who i can patch it.

thanks

Comment: Look for files with "gdbserver" in their names in the valgrind source code.